# Kusto Column with JSON array to separate rows

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to write a kusto query that would expand a JSON array column into separate result rows and also include other columns in each result row.

So far, I was able to write a query retrieving and projecting the data so an "Entities" column contains JSON array:

```
traces
| where customDimensions.MessageTemplate == 'Entities found for input \'{SearchText}\': {@Entities}'
| project
    timestamp,
    ClientIP = client_IP,
    ClientCity = client_City,
    ClientStateOrProvince = client_StateOrProvince,
    ClientCountryOrRegion = client_CountryOrRegion,
    SearchText = customDimensions.SearchText,
    Entities =  customDimensions.Entities
```

This resulted with the following output:
[image]

Then, I tried adding  `| mv-expand Entities` operator, yet it doesn't affect the output in any way, I get the same output each time. I'd expect the following result instead:

| timestamp [UTC] | ClientIP | ClientCity | ClientStateOrProvince | ClientCountryOrRegion | SearchText | EntityId | EntityName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-20T17:20:34.0327743Z | 0.0.0.0 | SomeCity | SomeState | SomeCountry | 155042 | 1 | Some entity 1 |
| 2023-07-20T17:20:34.0327743Z | 0.0.0.0 | SomeCity | SomeState | SomeCountry | 155042 | 2 | Some entity 2 |
| 2023-07-20T17:20:34.0327743Z | 0.0.0.0 | SomeCity | SomeState | SomeCountry | Random |  |  |

Note, that rows with empty JSON array are expanded into rows in the output, yet without any data for EntityID and EntityName. Do I miss anything when using the `mv-expand`?

Thanks

Comment: did you try with |  mv-expand EntityId=Entities.Id 
                         | mv-expand EntityName=Entities.Name

Comment: @ShivaPatpi Just tried it, I still get the same output with these two extra mv-expands

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

Input table taken **`x`** as- and used `mv-expand` and `bag-unpack`:

[image]

Now used below **`KQL`** query :

```
x
|mv-expand Entity
|evaluate bag_unpack(Entity)
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleMetrics?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2XPMQuDMBCG4T2/4sikkA46qaVLwdVCV5FymmBTTZQ2WqX63xux7WC58eF74WphYIADcDT28lo4cXKCCKQ2TKgmepi71CWDWBtpRgt81KhkAS5JCQB4jJ6luT5lRdnXnPRFJaeRtQSVoBFd1x6d2Sr%20Rnw6Zy5belaOze2G/7Vgswl%20tXAj4VIj2Z4MZFL9Tgwtav75gEyix7pDIyDH8tLpFovKWc19A%20vNkN4NAQAA)

Comment: I tried the following query:
traces
| where customDimensions.MessageTemplate == 'Entities found for input \'{SearchText}\': {@Entities}'
| project
    timestamp,
    ClientIP = client_IP,
    ClientCity = client_City,
    ClientStateOrProvince = client_StateOrProvince,
    ClientCountryOrRegion = client_CountryOrRegion,
    SearchText = customDimensions.SearchText,
    Entities =  customDimensions.Entities
| mv-expand Entities 
| evaluate bag_unpack(Entities)
But I'm still getting the same output as in the original question, maybe there's sth wrong with the Entities datatype?

Comment: @TomekCybulski it worked for me though

Comment: Seems that wrapping the customDimension.Entities into todynamic(tostring()) made it work:  todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.Entities)). Still, the row with empty array gets trimmed :(